# Freeing up JavaScript event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
$(".guide").focus(function(){
   $(this).removeClass("guide").val("");
});
```

I just need to know if there's something else I need to do to free up the event handler, or is it fine?

Comment: May be complement it with `.blur()` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [jQuery.fn.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for an event handler which is called once and then automatically detached.

```
$(".guide").one("focus", function(){
   $(this).removeClass("guide").val("");
});
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know about the `one()` handler. Cool!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean by 'free up the event handler' but I will guess..

Removing the class would work only if you are using a [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
 handler. In your situation where you explicitly attach the handler to elements you need to [.unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the handler from the element.

If you have a number of elements with a class of guide in a form then you will be best using delegate as follows

```
$('.guide').delegate('form', 'focus', function(){
   $(this).removeClass("guide").val("");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out - `$(this).removeClass("guide").unbind("focus").val("");`

Comment: @NeXXeuS Yeah that is what I said!